# File written to within Python's "with" clause and subsequently read by C# process is locked. Any probably causes?

Tags: c#, python, xml

A new XML file is created and written to in a Python process with the following code:

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    f.write(inXmlStr)
```

Subsequently, a C# process is launched by the Python process:

```
with open(self.outputLogPath, 'w') as f:
    self.csharpProcess = subprocess.Popen(processOpenCmd, stdout=f)
```

This C# process reads this newly created XML file using the `XmlDocument` class:

```
XmlDocument chXml = new XmlDocument();
chXml.Load(channelXml);
```

However, sometimes, the file is found to be locked and cannot be read by the C# process. It is found by using [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) that the process which is locking the XML file is indeed the Python process which had originally created and written to the file. This is unexpected, as the "with" clause of Python is supposed to close any opened files properly. Thus, I suspect this to be a Python bug.

I'm working on Windows 7 with Python 2.7 and .NET Framework 4

The exception stacktrace from the C# process is as follows:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\...\...\channel.xml' because it is being used by another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
at System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
at ChannelXmlRun(String xmlFile)
```

Any ideas about why this might be happening? Perhaps it is a known Python bug which you can point me to?

Comment: Are you sure the Python program has exited with `with` block when the C# program encounters a locked file?

Comment: @zmbq Yes, that should be the case, because the Python program's flow is linear, and the Popen statement comes after the `with` block.

Comment: What if you stop using `with` and close the file explicitly?

Comment: Yup, I have tried that already. But still get the same exception sometimes in the C# program

Comment: This is not the solution to the question, but maybe to the problem: what if you pass the XML into the C# process' stdin?

Comment: @ikaros45 Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't own the C# program's code (although I have read access). Else, I would love to pass the XML directly into the program, instead of passing the XML file.

Comment: Can you post the code where the file is created and then the subprocess called?